# GPIO.cleanup() did not work after continous cleanup process

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspberry-pi-os

I have one doubt, I'm using raspberry pi 3 b+.  When I playing Raspberrypi with a 5v relay, I have used the continuous cleanup() process. **After few minutes my raspberry pi was not cleanup(). It's not resetting GPIO pins.** Any idea?

```
import RPi._GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)

setup()

GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW )
print("Please Wait its setting up !!")
time.sleep(5)


try:
    while True:
        print("ON")
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        GPIO.cleanup()
        time.sleep(4)
        setup()
        
        
        # print("OFF")
        # GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
        # time.sleep(3)
   
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()

    print("Bye")
    exit()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This is my python code. **Actually GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW) this line not worked :(.
So i have used GPIO.cleanup() and setup() GPIO frequently instead of  GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)**. After few minutes my raspberry pi completely did not work which means *it did not reset GPIO*. Also, I have changed my OS also. Still, it's not resetting. Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If I had to guess you are trying to drive a 5V relay from the Pi's 3V3 GPIO.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.